# Sum of Hours,MInutes in PivotUI JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, pivottable.js

[image: Example]

[pivotUI js](https://pivottable.js.org/examples/) 
I am having issue with [pivotUI js](https://pivottable.js.org/examples/) (chart creation JS).
i want to calculate duration field's total value as hours:min  format. but pivotUI js default functions are not helpful for my requirements.
i want to create custom function for calculate that duration to hours and minutes format.
any suggestions ?
my code is like below.

```
 var renderers = $.extend($.pivotUtilities.renderers, $.pivotUtilities.export_renderers, $.pivotUtilities.gchart_renderers, $.pivotUtilities.derivers);
                    var tpl = $.pivotUtilities.aggregatorTemplates;
                    $("#output").pivotUI(data.data, {
                        renderers: renderers,
                        rows: ["fieldOne", "fieldTwo", "fieldThree", "Duration"],
                        cols: [],
                        //hiddenAttributes: ["Total"],
                        aggregators: {
                            "Total Time": function () {
                                return tpl.sum()(["Duration"]);
                            }
                        },
                        aggregatorName: "Total Time"
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

after debugging at very deep level, finally i got solution by adding custom function for calculating duration on **pivot.js** file.

**step 1:** firstly define your custom variables on js, like wise other variables used in pivot.js (hourMinuteFormat,hourMinuteInt are custom variables).
eg:

```
var PivotData, addSeparators, aggregatorTemplates, aggregators, dayNamesEn, derivers, getSort, locales, mthNamesEn, naturalSort, numberFormat, pivotTableRenderer, renderers, sortAs, usFmt, usFmtInt, usFmtPct, zeroPad, hourMinuteFormat, hourMinuteInt;
```

**Step 2:** create function which get duration and calculate total hours and total mins by logic as below.

```
 hourMinuteFormat = function (opts) {
            var defaults;
            defaults = {
                separator: ":"
            };
            opts = $.extend({}, defaults, opts);
            return function (x) {
                var totalh = Math.floor(x / 60);
                if (totalh < 10)
                {
                    totalh = "0" + totalh;
                }
                var totalm = x % 60;
                if (totalm < 10)
                {
                    totalm = "0" + totalm;
                }
                var result = totalh + opts.separator + totalm;
                return result;
            };
        };
        hourMinuteInt = hourMinuteFormat();
```

**Step 3:** After that need to create one more function which accept duration as "hh:mm" format and do further process to split it using ":" and store on different variables like hours,minutes.

```
 HoursMinutes: function (formatter) {
                if (formatter == null) {
                    formatter = hourMinuteInt;
                }

                return function (arg) {
                    var attr;
                    attr = arg[0];
                    return function (data, rowKey, colKey) {
                        return {
                            sum: 0,
                            push: function (record) {
                                if (record[attr]) {
                                    var minute = parseInt((record[attr]).split(':')[1]);
                                    var hour = parseInt((record[attr]).split(':')[0]) * 60;
                                    return this.sum += minute + hour;
                                }
                            },
                            value: function () {
                                return this.sum;
                            },
                            format: formatter,
                            numInputs: attr != null ? 0 : 1
                        };
                    };
                };
            },
```

**Step 4:** find `$.pivotUtilities` array where other default functions are defined there define your custom function Like below:

```
 $.pivotUtilities = {
            aggregatorTemplates: aggregatorTemplates,
            aggregators: aggregators,
            renderers: renderers,
            derivers: derivers,
            locales: locales,
            naturalSort: naturalSort,
            numberFormat: numberFormat,
            sortAs: sortAs,
            PivotData: PivotData,
            hourMinuteFormat: hourMinuteFormat //custom function
        };
```

**Step 5:** after that in your file where you want  to calculate duration, you need to use function named **HoursMinutes()** as below.

```
 var renderers = $.extend($.pivotUtilities.renderers, $.pivotUtilities.export_renderers, $.pivotUtilities.gchart_renderers, $.pivotUtilities.derivers);
                    var tpl = $.pivotUtilities.aggregatorTemplates;
                    $("#output").pivotUI(data.data, {
                        renderers: renderers,
                        rows: ["fieldOne", "fieldTwo", "fieldThree", "Duration"],
                        cols: [],
                        aggregators: {
                            "Total Time": function () {
                                return tpl.HoursMinutes()(["Duration"]);
                            }
                        },
                        aggregatorName: "Total Time"
                    });
```

i hope its understandable, if any one having query, then can ask me.

Comment: I tried this, but got the following error: tpl.HoursMinutes is not a function.